# 3DSecure ACSURL Fails / Timeout after 15 mins of inactivity

Tags: opayo, 3d-secure

We are finding about 15-20 3DS v1 transactions per day are being declined with the "Timeout after 15 minutes of inactivity. This is usually because the customer closed their browser" error.

We have spoken to the customers and it seems it is an issue directing to the ASCURL, as they aren't closing their browsers.

Upon further investigation we have found the **fails** are to URLS that state:-
**"System is currently unavailabe, sorry for the inconvenience!"**

Examples:-

```
https://secure7.arcot.com/acspage/cap?RID=25624&VAA=B
https://secure7.arcot.com/acspage/cap?RID=25420&VAA=B
https://secure7.arcot.com/acspage/cap?RID=29132&VAA=B
```

To be clear (as we aren't passing any details for security), a **working** ASCURL with no parameters gives a different error:-
**"Your authentication could not be completed because of a system error. If this happens consistently, please contact your CSR."**

Example:-

```
https://secure4.arcot.com/acspage/cap?RID=55672&VAA=B
```

Does anyone have any idea where to start with this?

Comment: We're experiencing similar issues. I believe it's related to Chrome introducing a new SameSite cookie policy, which prevents the payment session from being transferred via the 3D-Secure iframe. So the payment session gets lost at the 3DS stage, and eventually gets reported as a timeout in Sage Pay.